# structuring simple external API calls with MVC in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

First time trying to create a simple web app with external API call, and I'm not sure how to structure it properly. Any tips with be greatly appreciated!

Imagine there exists 5 players. Each player has a name. The API call will return the player ID given the name. I want to display them (for right now) on the show page.

Player Controller Show

```
def show
        @player = Player.find(params[:id])

        api = RiotApi.new
        @info = api.get_summoner_id("randomplayer") #returns JSON format {"randomplayer" => {"id"=>12345, ... } }  end
```

Player Show Page

```
some other code...
<%= @info["randomplayer"]["id"]%>
```

Right now there are plenty of things wrong with it that I would like to fix.

First is the API call exists within the show page. I believe the MVC structure propells me to add the API call in the model instead, but how do I call it back to the controller and the view?

Second is I am hard coding how to get id itself. Although this is for testing purposes (just want to see I am actually on the right track), this does not utilize the Player class at all. Furthermore, @info entirely depends on what I define it as in the show action, which is definitely not what I want.

How should I approach this?

Comment: https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Comment: that was  a great read, thanks for sharing!